# Php login system bug

Tags: php, html, sql, database, authentication

So, I have recently set up a PHP login system with my database and it works perfectly apart from one small bug. I am new to PHP so I don't fully understand what the error message is, please help me out here. 
The code is as follows:

```
<?php #admin/index.php 
           #####[make sure you put this code before any html output]#####

//connect to server
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or 
       die('could not connect: '.          mysqli_connect_error());

//select db
mysqli_select_db($dbc, 'examples') or die('no     db connection');

//check if the login form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['go'])){
   #####form submitted, check data...#####

    //step 1a: sanitise and store data into vars(storing encrypted password)
$usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,     htmlentities($_POST['u_name']));
$psw = SHA1($_POST['u_pass']) ; //using SHA1() to encrypt passwords  

    //step2: create query to check if username and password match
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$usr' AND pass='$psw'  ";

//step3: run the query and store result
$res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

//make sure we have a positive result
>>>if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1){<<<
     #########  LOGGING IN  ##########
    //starting a session  
            session_start();

            //creating a log SESSION VARIABLE that will persist through pages   
    $_SESSION['log'] = 'in';

    //redirecting to restricted page
    header('location:restricted.php');
} else {
            //create an error message   
    $error = 'Wrong details. Please try     again'; 
}
}//end isset go
?>
```

I have marked the line on which the error message is refering to with >>>Content<<<. The error message is:

Warning: `mysqli_num_rows()` expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli_result`, boolean given in /home/a7686887/public_html/index.php on line 26

Please help me out on this one and please remember that I am new to PHP so well explained answers will help out a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
// $res returns a mysqli_result or bool, so check it first
if($res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q)){
    // code that depends on $res comes here
}
```

Your query fails.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is a problem with your sql statement because $res isn't a mysqli_result.

Best to check it before using it.

```
if ( $res )
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check you `$res` variable, from the PHP [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

`Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.`

My guess is that your query is returning `false` and you're passing it to the `mysqli_num_rows()` function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to look at any SQL errors. Your query returns a boolean, which only happens when the query fails.

Comment: -1 It's `mysqli`, not `mysql`. Connection is always first argument in `functional` approach.

Comment: So all I do is simply change "== 1" to "== -1"?